# MySQL Data Type to Store Negative Number

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, negative-number

I have a rating system that ranges from -1 to 5 through 0.

So i need to store the following values

```
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Which is the best data type considering i want to fetch a total count of each value (not sum) ?

Comment: Why not a `tinyint`?  That will take 1 byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with `TINYINT`, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). It takes 1 byte of storage and its range is -128 to 127.